# I said plt.grid=True instead of plt.grid(True) and now plt.grid is a boolean. How do I undo this?

Tags: numpy, matplotlib

I'm an idiot. The problem is basically in the title:
I accidentally set `plt.grid = True` instead of `plt.grid(True)` in jupyter notebook, in its own environment. Now `plt.grid` is a boolean and I'd like to have it back before I touched it. I tried searching for it, but it looks like I couldn't find the right words to search. Thanks for your help! -J

Comment: Restart the kernel.

Comment: `import importlib` & `plt = importlib.reload(matplotlib.pyplot)` if you absolutely must.